# Polylang & CPT UI: translate label name

Tags: wordpress, polylang

**The problem is:**
I need to translate *custom posts and taxonomies names* which is not available on the edit or create GUI of CPT UI. I thought maybe it was a feature of the Pro version but the documentation says nothing about that. What am I missing?

**What is NOT the problem:**

1. I have already enabled the CPT and taxonomies translations on the plugin settings.
2. I use a custom theme of my own creation so I have full control of templates.